# In PyQt5 printing a Qt5 graphisview is wrong on PDF, but o.k on Epson printer

Tags: python-3.x, printing, pyqt5, render

I write a small programm for creating graphics in python3.
I defined in Qt5 designer a window with a graphivsview.
In python3 (using PyCharm) i create rectangles through a scene

```
    scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
    self.gvCanvas.setScene(scene)
```

that works well.
Now I want to print my grapghicsview gvCanvas. I connect a button.clicked to print_widget. This is definded like this:

```
def print_widget(self):
    # Create printer
    printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter() #QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.HighResolution)
    printer.setPageSize(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.A4)

    # Create painter
    painter = QtGui.QPainter()
    # Start painter
    painter.begin(printer)
    # Grab a widget you want to print
    screen = self.gvCanvas.grab()     #editor.grab()
    # Draw grabbed pixmap
    painter.drawPixmap(10, 10, screen)
    # End painting. 
    painter.end()
```

Printing directly to my Epson printer, everything is o.k.
I definded also a PDF-Printer on my Ubuntu 18.04. (cups-pdf). This works fine for all my Software (for example LibreOffice). But the print/plot, which ist o.k on Epson-printer does not work on the Pdf-Printer. I get a completely blank sheet.
In some forum I find , to do it with scene.render oder graphicsview.render. But i do not understand it or am unable to prot it to python3 (seems to be in C++)

So question: How should my print_widget look like correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

having spent hours i finally found a solution (without just understanding painter/printer)

I replaced the screen....... and pixmap-statements by

```
    #screen = self.gvCanvas.grab()     #editor.grab()
    # Draw grabbed pixmap
    #painter.drawPixmap(10, 10, screen)
    self.gvCanvas.render(painter)
```

and it works